# How to output two arrays to an html table with a delete button to confirm delete

Tags: javascript

Here is my code to insert the movie info into the two arrays and then output it to the screen with a table.    How do I get the delete button to show up and to get the titles and directors on separate columns?

```
var titles  = [];
var names   = [];

var titleInput  = document.getElementById("title");
var nameInput   = document.getElementById("name");    
var messageBox  = document.getElementById("display");

function insert ( ) {
    titles.push( titleInput.value );
    names.push( nameInput.value );    

    clearAndShow();
}

function clearAndShow () {
    // Clear our fields
    titleInput.value = "";
    nameInput.value = "";
}

// Print the info to a table
function show() {
    document.write('<table>');
    document.write('<tr><th>Titles</th></tr>');

    for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        document.write('<tr><td>' + titles[i] + '</td></tr>');
    }
    document.write('<tr><th>Directors</th></tr>');

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        document.write('<tr><td>' + names[i] + '</td></tr>');
    }

    document.write('</table>');    
}
//delete Button-reset
```

Comment: what do you mean by delete?   like a button to just delete the table?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript I would use:

```
function addRow(title, director){
  return "<tr><td>" + title + "</td><td>" + director + "</td>" + deleteRowMarkup(title) + "</tr>";
}

function deleteRowMarkup(title){
  return '<td><button on-click="del(title)">Delete Row</button></td>';
}

function del(title){
  //carry out delete, most likely by removing Title/Description from the associated arrays.
}

function show(){
  document.write("<table>");
  document.write("<tr><th>Title</th><th>Director</th></tr>");
  var len = titles.length > names.length ? titles.length : names.length;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
    var t = titles.length > i ? titles[i] : "";
    var n = names.length > i ? names[i] : "";
    document.write(addRow(t,n)
  }

  document.write("</table>");
  document.write('<a href='#' on-click="clearAndShow">Delete</a>');
}
```

Im not 100% sure what you mean by a delete or reset button, but i put in an anchor which would call your `clearAndShow` function

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot the clearAndShow just makes it so that the fields clear out when you click on add movie for the insert option. I was looking for that when I print out the info to the table to have a delete option next to each value. Still not sure how to do that.